# Unzip and Split CSV file with Headers

Tags: python, csv, split, header

I've been trying to figure out how to unzip then split a large csv file into chunks but keep the header for each file. I've tried a few things here and there but am not savvy enough to make it work.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
def run():
    # Get filename
    subprocess.call( "path to file" ./original --recursive".split())
    filename = subprocess.check_output("ls original/ ".split()).strip()
    filename = 'original/' + filename
    enter code here
    # Ungzip then split file
    file_content = ungzip(filename)
    zip_content(split_content)

def ungzip(filename):
    with gzip.open(filename) as f:

        counter = 0;
        name_counter = 0
        split_content = ''
        for line in f:
            counter = counter + 1
            split_content = split_content + str(line)
            if(counter >= 250000):
                print '-----------'
                name_counter = name_counter + 1
                name_string = 'file' + str(name_counter)
                print "zipping " + name_string
                zip_content(split_content, name_string )
                split_content = ''
                counter = 0
    return file_content
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Linux. It's a simple Python script that should work on any machine. By not putting the right tag and the right title, you will never have an answer to your questions.